# Phone Auth Login Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble accessing the phone. The validation code goes but I get the following error.

> "the verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is
>   invalid"

I wonder what's wrong ?

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(emailField.text!, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
if error != nil {
        return
    }
}
guard let otpCode = passwordField.text else { return }
guard let verificationID = emailField.text else { return }

let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID, verificationCode: otpCode)

Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (success, error) in
    if error == nil {
        print("login success")
        print(success)
    }else {
        print("login error")
        print("error code:", (error?.localizedDescription))

    }
}

}
```

Comment: have you uploaded the certificates to firebase console, like the development & production ones ?

Comment: I've got the certificates and the Firebase set up. They all work, I just can't log in.

Comment: You know you have to do a verification of the phone number first to get a verificationID, which you use to signInAndRetrieveData?

Comment: Although I entered the verification code correctly, he's not logged in, what should I do?

Comment: As i can see in your code, you're making the call to verifyPhoneNumber(), this returns a verificationID, and this verificationID you need to use to make the signInAndRetrieveData() call. You are doing verificationID = emailField.text in between the calls which results in "the verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid"

Comment: I'm entering a phone number in the emailfield section. The verification code is coming in, but I can't log in. @AchidFarooq

Comment: @stakabekor do you fix this issue? I have the same problem.